# Cluttered JavaScript tags, how to improve index.html

Tags: javascript, performance, http

What can I do to better organize the tens of script tags I have included in my index?
I'd like to bring down the HTTP requests to a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common practice: combine all your `.js` files into one with a concatenation tool like [this one](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/22/introducing-combiner-a-javascriptcss-concatenation-tool/) (works with CSS too). Then also consider compressing the code with a minifier. [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) works well and is also used by the jQuery project.

Comment: Also, do some 'housekeeping' - determine if all the scripts are needed. Also, you could consider (if the resultant concatenated .js file is big) determining which scripts are needed for which pages and only serving those that are required on each page.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 common solutions for this problem - Library level and Application level.

#### Library

With some tools you combine all your scripts into one js file. At Atma.js we use `importer`, so that the lib. file looks like this

```
// import /src/a.js
console.log('do smth. with a');
// import /src/b.js
console.log('do smth. with b, or a');
```

This approach is better than simple file-concatenation, as `a.js` could have some nested imports.

There are also tools that watches all your sources for changes, and as you edit any file, this tools run the task for you, so that the resulted lib is always fresh and ready for debug. We have also UglifyJS, so additionally also minified version could be produced.

So Library is good as it doesnt require any additional framework/tools for the application itself.

#### Application layer ( Modules )

Here you use additional library on the client. There many, some of them are [requirejs](http://requirejs.org), [includejs](http://atmajs.com/include). We use the last one, as it can loads not only javascript, but also coffeescript, and styles (css, less), and any other text/html/template files.

Including/requiring the source, all nested dependencies are also loaded. And in development mode it looks like, as you loading N files separately - it is really good for debugging, as by any exception you have the line number and the file where it happened.

These tools have also compilers - so that for production you combine all resources into one js/css file.

Application layer approach brings `modules` into the game - I wont explain here why, but it plays a huge role in the app. architecture.

You have to review this two methods, and decide what may be better in your application. Having any further questions, don't hesitate to ask them in comments.

Comment: Nice and detailed, thank you.